# How to get and use network adapter name?

Tags: batch-file, networking, reconnect

I am working with the following script:

```
@echo off
netsh interface show interface | find "Connected"
if errorlevel 1 goto #
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" disabled
goto end
:#
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" enabled
:end
```

I am trying to find a way to get the name of the found network adapters and use the name(s) instead of `"Local Area Connection"`. The reason is that not everyone's adapters are named the same and I am trying to automate this task as much as possible.

How can I get the names of the found network adapters and use the name(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a more concise way to capture the interface name.

```
for /F "skip=3 tokens=3*" %G in ('netsh interface show interface') do echo %%H
```

Putting it all together

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=3 tokens=1,2,3* delims= " %%G in ('netsh interface show interface') DO (
    IF "%%H"=="Disconnected" netsh interface set interface "%%J" enabled
    IF "%%H"=="Connected" netsh interface set interface "%%J" disabled
)
pause
```

The `FOR /F` command is parsing the output of the `NETSH` command. It is skipping the header rows. It then splits up the output into 4 meta variables.

```
%%G            %%H            %%I              %%J
Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Disconnected   Dedicated        Wireless Network Connection
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Local Area Connection
```

Comment: @ChristopherMoore, I have updated my question with an explanation of what the `FOR /F` command is doing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. 
I do not see an option to PM you. Is that not a feature here?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore, StackOverFlow is very different from other bulletin board forums.  There is no direct contact from user to user.

Comment: If i were to post my email address here, would it instantly be taken down?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore, why would you want to.  Internet bots are always scraping websites for email addresses so that they can use them for spamming or other nefarious things.

Comment: Because I would like to contact you directly in the future.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore, sorry that is not how this works.  I am not giving out my email address or contact information to anyone here.

Comment: No problem - i understand and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
for /F "tokens=4*" %%a in ('netsh interface show interface ^| more +2') do echo %%a %%b
```